# How to get tag of the service by its class name in Symfony 5.4+

Tags: php, symfony, tags

Initial info: Symfony 5.4+, PHP 8+.

For example I have a class **EventService**. It's first parameter in constructor of type EventInterface.

```
<?php
class EventService 
{
    public function __construct(private EventInterface $event)
    {
    }

    public function execute()
    {
     // obtain tags of the $event
    }
}
```

There are several events that implement this interface

```
<?php

class Event implements EventInterface 
{
// no tags property in here
}
```

In the service.yaml I declared

```yaml
Event:
  public: true
  tags:
    - { name: 'foo', priority: 20 } 
    - { name: 'bar', priority: -10 }
```

How to get those tags "foo" and "bar" for the object $event in the EventService?

I tried to use **ContainerBuilder**, but it gives me an error "service not found".

```
$containerBuilder->findDefinitions($event::class)->getTags()
```

Comment: Are you using a compiler pass?

Comment: I edited your question, please check if I have not changed anything mistakenly (specifically the space between get and Tags()). And for the _"(if any)"_ does it mean you currently have the service not in the YAML file? And I guess you don't want to have that being a requirement, right?

Comment: Thats, @hekra. Yes, the class may or may not have tags. So if the class is tagged my listerer class should apply extra logic to it. The issue is I can't simple parse service.yaml, because there can be another service.yaml in the vendor

Comment: What do you mean by "tags of that class defined in the service.yaml file". You mean tag iterator ?